# How to hide cakephp log in console result phpunit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, testing, phpunit

When running unit test by phpunit on console, it always displays the message I input in logfile:
This the sample file I will test:

Sample.php

```
public funtion testThis() {
    CakeLog::write('error', "This is a test");
}
```

then when I run in console

> $ ./Console/cake test app

I will get this result:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.38 by Sebastian Bergmann.

............This is a test..........50/50 (100%)
```

Comment: Does the string actually get written into the logfile?

Comment: @BVengerov no it's not. Is it normal to get results like this? or there is something I need to add in running unit test to hide this?

Comment: I haven't used Cake, but imo it is not normal. Posted what might be your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the configuration / configure the logger. My guess is that it doesn't have where to write, so is using `STDOUT` or `STDERR` for output.

Try to set up it with [instructions from here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html) (choose the appropriate Cake version).